# Графики matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, график, matplotlib

Вечер добрый!
Вопрос из области детского сада, но все же.

Строю простейший график:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as r
example = {"mm1":{"x":[0,1,2,3], 
              "y":[0,1,2,3]},
           "mm2":{"x":[0,1,2,3],
              "y":[4,5,6,10]}}

for m,i in example.items():
       plt.title(m)
       plt.plot(i["x"], i["y"], "b")
       plt.grid(True, linestyle='-', color='0.75')
       plt.show()
```

[image: Соответственно получаю]

Возможно ли вместо числовых значений шкалы X, вывести псевдонимы?

Не [0.0, 0.5, 1.0  ...]  а [A, B , C, D]. 
Меня не интересует диаграмма по столбцам, где каждому столбцу можно задать имя.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, что вам будет гораздо удобнее работать с [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
plt.xticks(example['mm1']['x'], list('ABCD'))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пример с использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mm1':example['mm1']['y'], 'mm2':example['mm2']['y']}, \
                  index=list('ABCD'))
```

Получившийся DataFrame:

```
In [413]: df
Out[413]:
   mm1  mm2
A    0    4
B    1    5
C    2    6
D    3   10
```

Построение графика:

```
df.plot(grid=True)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]